# Nginx 403 Forbidden on serving large images

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have setup a Django application, in which user can upload his image and it is served by Nginx and Gunicorn.

I have a problem with uploading large image files which does not get appropriate permissions to be served by Nginx

```
location /medias/images/ {
        root /var/www/html;
}
```

When uploading files, the larger ones only get read permissions for the user, not for group/other:

```
-rw-------  1 user1 user1 4.9M Mar 15 14:35 File1.jpg
-rw-------  1 user1 user1 3.7M Mar 15 14:31 File2.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1 110K Mar 15 14:44 File3.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1  34K Mar 15 09:17 File4.docx
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1 136K Mar 15 14:45 File5.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1  92K Mar 15 14:22 File6.doc
-rw-------  1 user1 user1 4.4M Mar 15 14:25 File7.jpg
```

However the smaller images get their permissions fine and are served properly.

The point is that both uploading small and semi-large (3mb) image files are done by a same process.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have set `client_max_body_size 500M;` in nginx config ?

Comment: i have set `client_max_body_size 32M;` which i think is related to uploading the file, in this case file is uploaded but without correct permissions to be served

Answer (score 3):

Set the `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` [parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE) in your Django settings, in Bytes.

For example `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 20971520` equals 20MB.